# How can I schedule a job on Heroku for a selected day day?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, scheduled-tasks

I have a Rails app deployed on Heroku with the Heroku scheduler add-on and followed the following link: [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler#dynohour-costs). What I am attempting to do is set the following the `index` to be ran on the 18th of every month. My `index` method looks like the following:

```
def index 
    @hospital_bookings = HospitalBooking.scoped
    hospital_booking = @hospital_bookings
    @user = current_user

    if params[:format] == "pdf"
      @hospital_bookings = @hospital_bookings.where(:day => Date.today.beginning_of_month..Date.today.end_of_month)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render :pdf => "#{Date.today.strftime("%B")} Overtime Report",
               :header => {:html => {:template => 'layouts/pdf.html.erb'}}
        OvertimeMailer.overtime_pdf(@user, hospital_booking).deliver
      end
    end
  end
```

So that effectively when the rake task is ran on the 18th of every month this will fire my OvertimeMailer and email the user. I have currently in my in my `scheduler.rake`

```
task :overtime_report => :environment do
  if Date.today.??? # Date.today.wday == 5
  HospitalBooking.index
  end
end
```

I know the above rake task is wrong. But am trying to achieve something along these lines

Update

```
class OvertimeMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default :from => DEFAULT_FROM

 def overtime_pdf(user, hospital_booking)
  @hospital_bookings = hospital_booking
  @user = user
  mail(:subject => "Overtime", :to => user.email) do |format|
    format.text # renders overtime_pdf.text.erb for body of email
    format.pdf do
      attachments["hospital_bookings.pdf"] = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
        render_to_string(:pdf => "overtime",:template => 'hospital_bookings/index.pdf.erb', :layouts => "pdf.html")
      )
    end
  end
end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Something simple like;

```
task :overtime_report => :environment do
  if Date.today.day == 18
    HospitalBooking.index
  end
end
```

and then run your scheduler everyday.

But you don't want to be calling your controller index method like this from your rake task. HospitalBooking will be the model and not the controller as you are expecting. Your best option is to put your email/generating PDF as a callable method in your model and then call that from your task.

Comment: I have updated my question. But from my understanding you are suggesting to take the contents of my `def overtime` method and put it in the HospitalBooking model and then make this callable correct? Would upvote but don't have enough rep

Comment: Going by your answer just for test purposes it seems that when I run the following command `heroku run rake overtime_report` I get the following error: `undefined method `day=' for Mon, 25 Mar 2013:Date` I understand that .day must not be compatible?